# how to sum values in function lambda in dynamodb in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have some tables in dynamodb and I simply want to take a cost variable, of a service and create a function that adds (like sum(column)) up all from one id and returns the result. how can I do it

Answer (score 1):

Summing up values from a DynamoDB table requires a full table scan by design.
It's because you need to gather all values from the column you are trying to sum up.

Your question is similar to [Find Average and Total sum in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196282/find-average-and-total-sum-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [query](https://www.dynamodbguide.com/querying) with a *projection expression* to read all values for the attribute you wish to sum into an array, then sum the values in the array client side.

A query avoids the need to do a full table scan.

For this to work, the "id" you reference in "all from one id" must be a [partition key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html).